# XCode 6 and iOS 8 - Google APIs Client Library for Objective-C linker error

Tags: objective-c, google-api, google-drive-api, ios8, xcode6

After upgrading XCode from 5.1.1 to 6.0 cannot compile my project - get linker errors:

Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLDrivePermissionId", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GTLDrive_Sources.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLDriveChannel", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GTLDrive_Sources.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: what other architectures are you building in your app?  and does your app still build in Xcode 5.1.1?

Comment: Standard architecture

Comment: XCode 5.1.1 has the same error - because error appear after upgrade to latest Google API Library

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It works for me after upgrading the AdMob SDK.

Following the SDK Release Notes you have to link two additional Frameworks:
https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/ios/rel-notes

> 1. Official release for iOS 8 support.
> 2. Ad loading takes less time on the main thread on iOS 8.
> 3. Smart Banner ads are correctly displayed in landscape on iOS 8.
> 4. **Requires linking against two new frameworks: EventKit and EventKitUI.** These are auto-linked if modules and auto-linking frameworks are enabled.
> 5. Deprecated mediatedAdView property on GADBannerView.
> 6. Removed the previously deprecated loadAndDisplayRequest:usingWindow:initialImage: method on GADInterstitial.